# CREATE TABLE Как использовать $_POST при создании таблицы?

Tags: php

Есть код для создания таблицы:

```
$query = 'CREATE TABLE `...` ( `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `ball` INT NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB';
```

Он работает хорошо, но как сделать так, чтобы название таблицы можно было вводить не напрямую, а через переменную?
Идея в том, чтобы можно было задавать имя создаваемой таблицы через

`<input type="text" name="..." />`

Можно, допустим, передать `'name'` переменной `$b`... `$b = $_POST['...']`, но как указать `$b` в коде `CREATE ...`?

Или есть какой другой способ решения задачи?

Comment: Это буквально основы языка (конкатенация строк)

Comment: Есть строка в двойных кавычках. Туда можно писать переменные..... Ещё есть HEREDOC  и NOWDOC.

Comment: А в целом да, это основы и почему бы не прочитать хотя бы одну книгу по PHP?

Comment: Спасибо! Я всё понял, просто запутался в кавычках. Всё получилось.

Answer (score 0):

Получилось сделать так:

```
$query = "CREATE TABLE `$b` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `ball` INT NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB";
```